# should moveit.rviz be modified directly

Tags: rviz, moveit, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

should moveit.rviz be modified directly

should one directly edit moveit.rviz (generated by Moveit Setup Assistant - MSA) or there's another way to configure how rviz is loaded? e.g. what rviz plugins to use

For example, one has configured this moveit.rviz for one robot. Another one uses MSA to generate config package for another robot but he still wants to imports the configuration from the last moveit.rviz. Should he just manually edit the 2nd moveit.rviz? I am quite certain this process is error-prone. Is there a better way?

I am using ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/304192/should-moveit.rviz-be-modified-directly/) by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 110 on 2018-09-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Should he just manually edit the 2nd moveit.rviz?

It's just a simple text file, so editing it would be one option.

> I am quite certain this process is error-prone. Is there a better way?

Copying the `.rviz` file from the other package to the new moveit config package?

There is nothing special about the file (ie: nothing robot specific per se), so you can just copy them.

Another option would be to open the `.rviz` config file from the first package *while* you have the second loaded, and then save the RViz config to the `.rviz` file in the second moveit config package (essentially overwriting it).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2018-09-25**:
Since I am mentioning about two different robots, is it possible to simply save to overwrite? I see in .rvi z there's some sort of robot description i.e  link names. If there's a better porting that keeps the differences for robots, that'll be convenient

**Comment by [roskidos](https://answers.ros.org/users/3257/roskidos/) on 2018-09-25**:
The config rviz save and overwrite does not keep the differences from the 1st rviz even though it "smartly" updates the robot descriptions/names for the 2nd robot. So, instead I resort to use a diff and merge to port the 1st rviz to the 2nd one. But like you said, this is a direct manual edit

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-09-26**:
The link names are updated every time you save the config. They are read from the `robot_description` parameter by the displays that need/use them.

I'm not sure I understand you when you write:

> The config rviz save and overwrite does not keep the differences from the 1st rviz